# Python: three different delimiters between columns, column to list, quickest way

Tags: python, delimiter

I have data (below) with three different delimiters (the first has a space to the number, the second 3 spaces to the number and the final column a space and then a tab to the number) and I want to be able to generate a list containing sequential values from each column.

```
 8000.5   16745     0.1257
 8001.0   16745     0.1242
 8001.5   16745     0.1565
 8002.0   16745     0.1595
 8002.5   16745     0.1093
 8003.0   16745     0.1644
```

I tried some stuff with re. after converting to a string to see if I could parse it this way but it seemed a little bit long-winded to convert and I was wondering if anyone knew a quicker way. Ideal output would be

```
list 1 = [8000.5, 8001.0, 8001.5 ...]
list 2 = [16745, 16745, 16745, ...]
list 3 = [0.1257, 0.1242, 0.1565, ...]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `.split()`; it'll take any amount of whitespace and split on that (ignoring leading and trailing whitespace altogether):

```
>>> ex = ' 8000.5   16745     0.1257'
>>> ex.split()
['8000.5', '16745', '0.1257']
```

If you need floats instead of strings, simply apply `float()` to each value using `map`:

```
>>> ex = ' 8000.5   16745     0.1257'
>>> map(float, ex.split())
[8000.5, 16745.0, 0.1257]
```

Comment: Is `strip` actually necessary?  I think just using `split` should take care of it.

Comment: Any better idea on how to get the list of column?

Comment: @mgilson: heh, if you split on other values leading items are included in the split (e.g. `'/one/two'.split('/')` > `['', 'one', 'two']`. But without an argument, indeed, the strip is not needed.

Comment: @Mayli: better how? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: Yeah, I was surprised when you said that since it goes against the documented behavior for python 2.7 -- I was wondering if this had been changed in python 3k but (thankfully) I don't think it has changed.

Answer (score 1):

use `split()`

```
strs = """ 8000.5   16745     0.1257
 8001.0   16745     0.1242
 8001.5   16745     0.1565
 8002.0   16745     0.1595
 8002.5   16745     0.1093
 8003.0   16745     0.1644"""

list_col= map(list,zip(*(map(float,x.split()) for x in strs.split('\n'))))

print(list(list_col))
```

**output:** list of list of columns

```
[[8000.5, 8001.0, 8001.5, 8002.0, 8002.5, 8003.0], [16745.0, 16745.0, 16745.0, 16745.0, 16745.0, 16745.0], [0.1257, 0.1242, 0.1565, 0.1595, 0.1093, 0.1644]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
txt = """ 8000.5   16745     0.1257
 8001.0   16745     0.1242
 8001.5   16745     0.1565
 8002.0   16745     0.1595
 8002.5   16745     0.1093
 8003.0   16745     0.1644 """

data = zip(*((float(s) for s in row.split()) for row in txt.split('\n')))
```

results in

```
[(8000.5, 8001.0, 8001.5, 8002.0, 8002.5, 8003.0),
 (16745.0, 16745.0, 16745.0, 16745.0, 16745.0, 16745.0),
 (0.1257, 0.1242, 0.1565, 0.1595, 0.1093, 0.1644)]
```

Comment: use `map()` instead of two for loops.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: I think if you look carefully, you will find our answers do the same amount of work in the same order; the only difference is, I find mine easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to do it (`s` is the initial string):

```
>>> [map(float, col) for col in zip(*map(str.split, s.splitlines()))]
[[8000.5, 8001.0, 8001.5, 8002.0, 8002.5, 8003.0],
 [16745.0, 16745.0, 16745.0, 16745.0, 16745.0, 16745.0],
 [0.1257, 0.1242, 0.1565, 0.1595, 0.1093, 0.1644]]
```